# Knock Out data binding

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a question about data binding using knockout.

Here's the problem: I have a table, I what I would like to do is that when a row in table is clicked, I want the values of the row to appear in the input fileds which are located above the table.

so here'

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
                        <tr data-bind="click: doSomething">     
                            <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text:staff"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: ftype"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: value"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: message"></td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

In my viewmodel, I have the following function:

```
doSomething: function(data) { 
        var self = this;      
        self.date(data.date);        
        self.staff(data.staff); 
        self.ftype(data.ftype);
                   self.value(data.value);
                   self.message(data.message);  

    }
```

Here's the  error I am getting:

```
["Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError:… is not defined;↵Bindings value: click: doSomething", "views/myView/index", Object]
   0: "Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError: doSomething is not          defined;↵Bindings value: click: doSomething"
 1: "views/myView/index"
  2: Object
length: 3
 __proto__: Array[0]
```

Let me know if I need to provide any more details. I will appreciate your help fplks!

Answer (score 1):

A very basic pattern for this type of thing is to have an array of items and a `selectedItem` observable that you populate when selecting a row.

Then, you can use the `with` binding around a section to create your editor.

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectedCustomer">     
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

<div data-bind="with: selectedCustomer">
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
</div>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Z6VPV/

Comment: let me try this and I will get back to you in a minute

Comment: Btw, is there something wrong with they way I have it written? If so, then how can I fix it? I already have an observable array that I am populating my table with and it works. But when I add the click event, it gives me parse error and the table doesnt display the data anymore

Comment: Best bet is to get something in jsFiddle that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your model to the view

```
 var currentViewModel = function(){
   this.doSomething = function(data){
      var self = this;      
      self.date(data.date);        
      self.staff(data.staff); 
      self.ftype(data.ftype);
                 self.value(data.value);
                 self.message(data.message);  
  }
var viewModel = new currentViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: What goes in the doSomething method?

Comment: I am trying to bind the values in the dosomething function to my input fields so that the values get displayed when I click the row

Comment: are the two lines of code below go into the function or stay outside the fucntion ?